# Xamarin Gets WiFi List from Android

Tags: xamarin.forms

```
###################################
#    MainActivity.cs
###################################
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Content;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Net.Wifi;
using System.Text;
using Java.Lang;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using StringBuilder = System.Text.StringBuilder;
using Menu = Android.Views.Menu;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(App1.Droid.Wifi))]
namespace App1.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "App1", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize )]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }

      
    }


   
    public class Wifi : IWifi
    {
        private Context context = null;

        public Wifi()
        {
            this.context = Android.App.Application.Context;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetAvailableNetworksAsync()
        {
            IEnumerable<string> availableNetworks = null;

            // Get a handle to the Wifi
            var wifiMgr = (WifiManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);
            var wifiReceiver = new WifiReceiver(wifiMgr);

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                // Start a scan and register the Broadcast receiver to get the list of Wifi Networks
                context.RegisterReceiver(wifiReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.ScanResultsAvailableAction));
                availableNetworks = wifiReceiver.Scan();
            });

            return availableNetworks;
        }


        [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = false)]
        class WifiReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
        {
            private WifiManager wifi;
            private List<string> wifiNetworks;
            private AutoResetEvent receiverARE;
            private Timer tmr;
            private const int TIMEOUT_MILLIS = 10000; // 20 seconds timeout

            public WifiReceiver()
            {

            }
            public WifiReceiver(WifiManager wifi)
            {
                this.wifi = wifi;
                wifiNetworks = new List<string>();
                receiverARE = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            }

            public IEnumerable<string> Scan()
            {
                tmr = new Timer(Timeout, null, TIMEOUT_MILLIS, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
                wifi.StartScan();
                receiverARE.WaitOne();
                return wifiNetworks;
            }

            public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                IList<ScanResult> scanwifinetworks = wifi.ScanResults;
                foreach (ScanResult wifinetwork in scanwifinetworks)
                {
                    wifiNetworks.Add(wifinetwork.Ssid);
                }

                receiverARE.Set();
            }

            private void Timeout(object sender)
            {
                // NOTE release scan, which we are using now, or we throw an error?
                receiverARE.Set();
            }
        }
    }
}

###################################
#    MainPage.xaml.cs
###################################
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App1
{
    public interface IWifi
    {
        Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetAvailableNetworksAsync();
    }

    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> _wifiService = null;
            _wifiService = await DependencyService.Get<IWifi>().GetAvailableNetworksAsync();

            txtlog.Text = _wifiService.Count().ToString();
            wifilist.ItemsSource = _wifiService;

            

            //Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60), () =>
            //{
            //    // do something every 60 seconds
            //    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            //    {
            //        IEnumerable<string> _wifiService = null;
            //        _wifiService = await DependencyService.Get<IWifi>().GetAvailableNetworksAsync();
            //        wifilist.ItemsSource = _wifiService;

            //        //txtlog.Text = _wifiService.Count<int>();
            //        //editLog.add
            //    });

            //    return true; // runs again, or false to stop
            //});




            //IEnumerable<string> test1 = new IEnumerable<string>;

            //wifilist.

            //ListView listview = FindViewByID<ListView>(Resources.Id)
            //listview.setAdapter(adapter);

            //List<string> lstItems;

            //for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
            //{


            //}

            //wifilist.ItemsSource = lstItems;

        }
    }
}

###################################
#    MainPage.xaml.cs
###################################
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.app1" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
    <application android:label="App1.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

I tried following the example, but I can't get the wifi list. What am I doing wrong?
Here is a link to the example I referenced.

[referenced example](https://so.muouseo.com/qa/d1094dn216e4.html)

I plan to use Android 10 or higher.
And I'm going to test it by putting Android OS on the Raspberry Pi board in the development environment.

Comment: please post the **relevant** bits of code.  Posting **everything** just makes it very unlikely anyone is going read all of it in an attempt to help.  Are you getting any errors or exceptions?  Have you debugged the code to narrow down the problem?  "I can't get the wifi list" is not a very helpful description of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

From the code, I understood that you are trying to get the list of available wifi connections.

I have tried your code and I am able to get the wifi list.

Please check whether you have done below things, if not please do

- enable device location
- allow location permission for your app (either from your code or from device settings)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for answer. It works normally in Android 5.1 version.

If you run the app in Android 10 or higher version, you cannot get the Wi-Fi list. Can different versions have different feature behavior?

Comment: I have tried the solution in Android 11 only!!